# What happens to velocity when Time equals zero?

Tags: kinematics, time, velocity, differentiation

I am not formally educated in Science but natural questions have always intrigued me.The way I put it is that I am married to Commerce but Science has been a childhood love. Now I have this very basic question here and excuse me for being too naive. We have studied in school that velocity = Displacement / Time. What happens to velocity when Time equals zero? I understand that the object must be in motion to calculate velocity hence time comes into play. However, does that mean the object attains infinite velocity if time equals zero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Velocity is not *displacement over time* but *displacement over **change in** time*. (*Displacement* itself is a word for *change in position*)

You calculate velocity as $$v=\frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}$$ or in the instantaneous case written as a differential ratio:

$$v=\frac{d s}{d t}$$

There is no value of time involved here - only a *change* or *difference* in the value of time. You might, though, in some literature now and then see a single $t$ written instead of $\Delta t$. But that is just short-hand, where that single $t$ still means *change in* time.

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that "displacement" is a short-hand way of saying "change in position." Velocity is a _rate_. That is, a ratio of two changes.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a deep question, and it does not just apply to velocity: there's a more general question about whether it makes sense to talk about ratios between two quantities as the two quantities get very small, and ultimately reach zero.  The answer is that it does make sense, but you need to develop a whole new area of mathematics for this.

A very brief sketch of how you can do this is as follows.

### Limits

The first step is to develop a notion of a *limit*: what this means is that, if you have an infinite series of numbers you can ask if that series of numbers is somehow approaching a number, or whether it isn't, and, if it is, what that number is.

Here is a series of numbers: $9/10, 99/100, 999/1000, 9999/10000, \ldots$; we can define these numbers as

$$S_n = \frac{10^n - 1}{10^n}\quad n = 1, 2, \ldots$$

And the question is: do these numbers converge to some limit, and if so what is the limit?  Well, doing a bit of arithmetic we can see that

$$
\begin{align}
  1 - S_n &= 1 - \frac{10^n - 1}{10^n}\\
          &= \frac{10^n}{10^n} - \frac{10^n - 1}{10^n}\\
          &= \frac{1}{10^n}
\end{align}
$$

And this means that we can make $1 - S_n$ as small as we like, and in particular if we pick any positive number $\epsilon$, we can pick an $n$ such that $S_m < \epsilon$ for *all* $m > n$.

If this is the case then we say that $S_n$ does have a limit, and it's $1$.

There are a lot of subtleties about limits: I've given only a rather simple case where it's kind of obvious what the limit is and we don't have to worry very much, but there are a lot of powerful tools you can develop to check whether sequences have limits and what the limits are if so.  One of the most important things about limits is that they involve reasoning about *infinite* processes, and I think that this is perhaps the first time this was done in mathematics.  If you can't reason about limits you end up with all sorts of paradoxes, many of which were discovered by [Zeno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno_of_Elea), and were based on not realising that some infinite *sums*, which look like $a_1 + a_2 + \cdots$ can actually have finite limits.

This notion of a limit is really important because it allows us to reason about things we can't really ever, quite, do: we can't, obviously, compute an infinite number of the $S_n$ I talked about above, but once we have this notion of a *limit* tied down we can start to reason about what this series turns into, if we go infinitely far along it.  This ability to reason about infinite processes is critically important, and it probably marks the start of modern mathematics.

There is a notation for limits which I'll use below, which, in this case is

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n = 1$$

This just reads as 'the limit as $n$ goes to $\infty$ of $S_n$ is $1$'  Additionally

$$x \to y$$

reads as '$x$ goes to $y$'.

[The Wikipedia page on limits of sequences is perhaps a good starting point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence).

### Continuity

The next step is to think about whether some quantities are *continuous*: whether they jump around somehow over time, or not.  This is another big subject, but I'll just give a specific example: let's take the position of some object which is moving.  Call this position $p$, and since it depends on time, $t$ we'll write $p(t)$.  And we have some intuition that objects don't somehow jitter around: over short enough periods of time they move only short distances.

Well, we can define this in terms of sequences it turns out: let's pick some moment of time, $T$ and ask if $p$ is continuous there.  Well, we can do this by first of all constructing a sequence of times which has a limit $T$: this is easy because if we have a sequence which converges to *any* number, we can just multiply every element suitably to get one that converges to $T$.  Call the elements of this sequence $t_n, n=1,2, \ldots$: using the notation above $\lim_{n\to\infty} t_n = T$.  Now we can invent another sequence: $p(t_n)$.

And now we can ask: does the sequence $p(t_n)$ converge to some limit as $t_n$ converges to $T$: does $\lim_{n\to\infty} p(t_n)$ exist.  If it does, then we say that $p$ is continuous at $T$, and the limit of the $p(t_n)$ is $p(T)$.  We write this as

$$\lim_{t\to T} p(t) = p(T)$$

You can imagine things which move in such a way that their position *isn't* continuous: imagine something that sits at $0$ until some time $T$ and then suddenly jumps – perhaps teleports or something – to 1: its position is not continuous at $t=T$.

### Differentials: velocity

Finally we can put this together.  We have a notion that the velocity of something (in one dimension) is how far it moves in a given time: the average velocity from, say $t_1$ to $t_2$ is given by

$$v_\text{average} = \frac{p(t_2) - p_(t_1)}{t_2 - t_1}$$

Well, let's have $t_2 = t_2 + \delta t$, where $\delta t$ is the interval we want to average over.  So now

$$v_\text{average} = \frac{p(t_1 + \delta t) - p(t_1)}{\delta t}$$

We can also define $\delta p(t_1) = p(t_1 + \delta t) - p(t_1)$ ($\delta x$ generally means 'a small amount of $x$'), and we get this

$$v_\text{average} = \frac{\delta p(t_1)}{\delta t}$$

OK, so now we can ask the limit question again: does this thing have some kind of sensible value if $\delta t \to 0$: is

$$\lim_{\delta t \to 0} \frac{\delta p}{\delta t}$$

defined?

Well, it's not defined if $p$ is not continuous at $t_1$, obviously.  But even if it is continuous it may not be defined.  We can do the same sequence trick: find a sequence which converges to $0$, and then use this as the $\delta t$'s, and ask if the resulting sequence of $\delta p/\delta t$ converges.

If it does, then we *define* a thing written as $dp/dt$ as being the limit:

$$\frac{dp}{dt} = \lim_{\delta t \to 0} \frac{\delta p}{\delta t}\quad\text{definition of $dp/dt$}$$

and we say that

$$v(t_1) = \frac{dp(t_1)}{dt}\quad\text{definition of $v$}$$

And this is how we define the velocity, $v$ (at $t_1$, but we can pick any value for $t_1$ of course, so long as the limit exists there).

This is called differentiation, and it's an extremely important part of mathematics and an even more important part of physics, because it lets us talk about things like velocity (the differential of position) and acceleration (the differential of velocity) and so on.  None of physics would really be possible without these tools.  The general name of these tools is [calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus), often also known as analysis (both names are kind of confusing, because there are other sorts of calculus, $\lambda$-calculus for instance, and 'analysis' also means lots of other things).

### The trick

The trick that's been done in all three cases is to somehow talk about something we can never do: we can never compute $S_\infty$, and we can never really divide $0$ by $0$, but what we can do is use an infinite number of steps to get closer and closer to those things in some well-defined way.

To realise how important this trick is, you need to know the names of one of the people who first developed it: Isaac Newton.  The other was Gottfried Leibniz, and of course there was [a big controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz%E2%80%93Newton_calculus_controversy) about who got there first (they developed it independently in fact).

To realise how deep this trick is it's worth realising that some aspects of it did not really get sorted out for a century or longer.  For instance it's obvious that things which are differentiable must be continuous, but is the converse true: are functions which are continuous differentiable almost everywhere?  Well, no, they may not be, and this was not understood until [1872](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

Finally note that the approach I've sketched to thinking about continuity & differentiability using sequences is only one of many possible ones, and not even the most common one: I just did it this way because I wanted to start with sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Velocity is the rate of change of distance moved by an object. Some amount of time, however short it may be, must elapse for you to even define this quantity. Usually, we consider time $t = 0$, to denote the starting time of our observation. Your definition $v = \frac{\text{displacement}}{\text{time}}$ makes sense if the body was initially ($t=0$) at rest at a position $x = 0$ and you try to measure its velocity at a later time $t$.

A more general definition would be, $$v =\displaystyle \frac{\text{distance covered}}{\text{time elapsed}} = \displaystyle\frac{\text{final position - initial position}}{\text{final time - initial time}}= \displaystyle\frac{x_2 - x_1}{t_2 - t_1}.$$

The most general definition would involve expressing velocity as a differential of position with respect to time. $$v = \frac{dx}{dt}$$

Answer (score 1):

When you write speed = distance / time, it means that for a very short time the object will travel a proportionately very short distance, such that their ratio is constant for any (short enough) time. That's the idea of differentiation (in this case, differentiation of position with respect to time).

This assumes of course that the object doesn't "jump around", in other words, that the position is continuous. If the position jumps around all the time, we can't define a speed at all (that's quite intuitive actually).

Also (for the more mathematically itchy) for the speed to be defined always unequivocally, the velocity itself must also be continuous.

Answer (score 1):

> We have studied in school that velocity = Displacement / Time. What
>   happens to velocity when Time equals zero?

First, velocity *isn't* defined as the displacement $\Delta\mathbf{s}$ divided by the time $t$.  You might be thinking about the *average* velocity $\bar{\mathbf v}$ which is defined as the displacement divided by the *elapsed* time $\Delta t$ (the time over which the displacement took place):

$$\bar{\mathbf v} \equiv \frac{\Delta\mathbf{s}}{\Delta t}$$

or

$$\Delta\mathbf{s} = \bar{\mathbf v}\cdot\Delta t$$

Clearly, the displacement is zero when the elapsed time is zero (for finite $\bar{\mathbf v}$).

Now, the *instantaneous* velocity $\mathbf{v}$ is (in words) the average velocity *in the limit* that the elapsed time goes to zero:

$$\mathbf{v} \equiv \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0}\frac{\Delta\mathbf{s}}{\Delta t}$$

That is, $\mathbf{v}$ is the derivative with respect to time of the displacement:

$$\mathbf{v} \equiv \frac{d\mathbf{s}}{dt}$$

Answer (score 0):

If time is zero, displacement is also zero hence we have a $\frac00$ form which is indeterminate and hence we will need to increase time period of observation.Remember , the definition we are talking about is observed change in time and displacement as pointed in commnets beloe, I forgot to state this earlier

Comment: This is wrong. If t=0 you can still have a velocity, and it doesn’t guarantee anything up to an arbitrary constant on displacement.

Comment: @JakeRose In terms of how OP is wording it, this does make some sense (though clearing up OP's term usage would have made more sense).  That's mostly because OP is using "time" to mean a change in time, not an instantaneous time.  It follows that if you have no change in time, you also have no change in displacement, therefore trying to use it to determine velocity is pointless.

Comment: Thanks, obviously I forgot to add that explanation

Answer (score 0):

The thing with physics is that you can't randomly put up values in formulas. I know that the existence of the formula is because it is valid, but then it has certain limitations - we cannot consider the case for infinities since they are not a *realistic* situation.

This answer is based on what you say is $\Delta t =0$.

Like you said, that $v$ could turn out to be infinity if the time interval was zero. But then in reality we know that the displacement for the object (from our intuition - or common sense) is zero.

Hence, you get something indeterminate like $0/0$ which means that the formula has failed to give an output, since there is no definition for velocity without giving a realistic time interval.

If $\Delta t \to 0$, then you have to apply the differentiation concept instead, then you cannot get away with the fact that you have some sensible displacement, for there is a sensible time interval: then

$$v=dx/dt$$ This is what you would call the *instantaneous velocity* at a point. It may seem to you that $\Delta t = 0$ is instantaneous, and it really is kind of, but the velocity formula that you calculate for average velocities like $\Delta x/\Delta t$ would break down to these "indeterminate forms" that I mentioned above.

$\Delta t \to 0$ saves the problem instead.